# Set the correct datetime format with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

I have trouble setting the correct datime format with Pandas, I do not understand why my command does not work. Any solution?

```
 date  = ['01/10/2014 00:03:20']
 value = [33.24]
 df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'index':date})
 df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
date  = ['01/10/2014 00:03:20']
value = [33.24]

#create index by date list
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value},index=date)
#use Y for match YYYY, y is for match YY years format
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print (df)

                     value
2014-10-01 00:03:20  33.24
```

If want `index` column name is necessary use `[]` for avoid selecting `RangeIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'index':date})
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print (df)

   value               index
0  33.24 2014-10-01 00:03:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a column 'index' is a bit confusing, changed it to 'index_date'.

```
import pandas as pd

date  = ['01/10/2014 00:03:20']
value = [33.24]
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'index_date':date})
df['index_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["index_date"], errors="coerce")
```

Output of `df`:

```
    value      index_date
0   33.24   2014-01-10 00:03:20
```

And if you run `df.dtypes`

```
value                float64
index_date    datetime64[ns]
```